# Switch between native ios code and html (phonegap)

Tags: ios, cordova

Is there a way to layer both ios code and html in a single view? Meaning when a user is on an ios device, instead of seeing the web view they can see the native ios view? This is so there is no need for a schema and another application to launch.

Answer (score 2):

You can embed a Cordova-enabled WebView inside a native iOS application:

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/hybrid/webviews/index.html